# How can I make a call to an api that was loaded globally while I am inside requirejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, backbone.js

I inherited a project that is using magento and foundation. I incorporated requirejs and backbone on top of this and I am trying to get a foundation orbit gallery working that is being loaded into the dom via hogan (render) in backbone.

The problem I am having is that foundation is already being loaded globally in one of the magento templates and when I render the slides in requirejs, the orbit gallery has already been built so it is not displaying the slide indicators.

Basically, I need to be able to call $(document).foundation(); from inside my backbone view in order to re-initialize the orbit container somehow whenever I change the slides.

Here is what is being loaded at the bottom of the dom from magento,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/package/theme/js/foundation/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/package/theme/js/foundation/foundation.interchange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/package/theme/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/package/theme/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/package/theme/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
```

Here is the gist of my requirejs view and what I am trying to accomplish

```
define([
    'generics/genericView',
    'foundation',
    'text!carousel.tpl'
], function(
    GenericView,
    foundation,
    visualCarouselTpl
) {

    return GenericView.extend({
        'el': 'html',

        'events': {
        },

        render: function() {
            var rederedTpl = Hogan.compile(visualCarouselTpl).render({"myImages": imagePaths});
            $(".my-carousel").prepend(rederedTpl);
            $(document).foundation();
        },

        initialize: function (params) {
            this.render();

            return this;
        },
    });
});
```

And here is the template

```
<ul data-orbit>
{{#myImages}}
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="{{src}}" alt="{{alt}}" />
        </a>
    </li>
{{/myImages}}
</ul>
```

In this particular example, I am requiring another copy of foundation in order for this module to see what "foundation" is when I call `$(document).foundation();`. This seems to create the carousel, but the indicators are not there I believe because the slides are being included after the carousel is rendered.

To sum up, I need to be able to do one of the following (preferably the first one)

1. Incorporate the global foundation api's into require and use it to re-initialize the obit gallery.
2. Require all of the same foundation files through require and re-initialize the orbit gallery that way. I however do not want to be loading the foundation libraries twice if possible, so I would need to figure out how to remove those from the dom first on this one. Though I guess I could load them twice if its just easier.

So far I have tried to call `$(document).foundation();` both with and without it being incorporated into require. There is a javascript error when not including it into require (because it does not see foundation), and there is a javascript error of

[image]
When foundation is in require.

Comment: Keep in mind Foundation will alter the global jQuery that it finds. Each time you require it (or include it in a script tag) it will try to do this. There's a good chance if you do it twice, it causes an error. Also ensure you don't have 2 versions of jQuery running.

Comment: @mikeapr4 I believe I may be adding jquery in twice. But that is for the same reason as foundation. I am not sure how I can get require to take the current jquery version into it. I tried removing the first loaded foundation from magento using removeItem, but I can not get that to work and my knowledge of magento is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recreation of your problem using [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), it's a small plugin that modifies the jQuery object also.

In this example, there is a Global jQuery added via `<script>`, this is version **2.2.4**, and within the RequireJS configuration, there is another, which is **3.2.1**. This way we can compare.

Run the code and see what happens.

```js
var globaljQuery = jQuery;

require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery-cookie": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min",
        "jquery": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min"
    }
});

require(['jquery-cookie'], function() {
  console.log("Old Global jQuery Version: " + globaljQuery().jquery);
  console.log("Old Global Cookie add-on exists: " + Boolean(globaljQuery.cookie)); 
  console.log("New Global jQuery Version: " + jQuery().jquery);
  console.log("New Global Cookie add-on exists: " + Boolean(jQuery.cookie)); 
});
```

```html
<!-- Global jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.3/require.min.js"></script>
```

The plugin in this case, understands it is in an AMD environment and uses RequireJS to access jQuery. Now 2 jQuery objects have been created, and unfortunately only 1 modified to include the plugin.

In your case, you cannot remove the globals right now, but your solution should be to use the globals within the RequireJS context.

This can be done in 2 ways:

A) Create a module with this code:

```
define(function() { return jQuery; });
```

and then use your `path` config to point `jquery` there.

B) Slightly cleaner is to use the [callback](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-callback) configuration option:

```
require.config({
  callback: function() {
    define('jquery', function() { return jQuery; });
  },
  ...
```

See it in action:

```js
var globaljQuery = jQuery;

require.config({
    callback: function() {
        define('jquery', function() { return jQuery; });
    },
    paths: {
        "jquery-cookie": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min",
        "jquery": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min"
    }
});

require(['jquery-cookie', 'jquery'], function(cookiePlugin, requiredjQuery) {
  console.log("Old and New Global jQuery equal?: " + (globaljQuery === jQuery));
  console.log("Global and Required jQuery equal?: " + (jQuery === requiredjQuery));
});
```

```html
<!-- Global jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.3/require.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get the following mike Old Global jQuery Version: 1.10.2
main.js:43 Old Global Cookie add-on exists: false
main.js:44 New Global jQuery Version: 3.2.1
main.js:45 New Global Cookie add-on exists: true. On your first set of code.

Comment: right, it proves this is the problem, have you tried my proposed solution?

Comment: I got this on the second set, Old and New Global jQuery equal?: true
main.js:47 Global and Required jQuery equal?: true after adding the callback.

Comment: Is this a jquery issue though? Or a foundation issue? After using the callback, could I use jquery inside require with foundation and it will work?

Comment: Looks like that error is gone, but it may have broken jquery in my app now because nothing is rendering.

Comment: the goal here is to have only 1 version of jQuery, using the callback means a 2nd one isn't created. With that in place, you can use jQuery wherever you like and know it's the right one. If you are loading Foundation globally, you could do the same with it (add the global to the requirejs context), two avoid it being run again, glancing over the 6.3.1 code, it looks like it would create a 2nd instance of Foundation which is probably a bad thing.

Comment: "but it may have broken jquery in my app" - I'm 100% certain that is not the case, but if your global version is *1.10* and the other version was *3.2.1*, there's a good chance you need to upgrade your global version as there's missing functionality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142204/discussion-between-metropolis-and-mikeapr4).